# Rudin's example of a monotone function with a dense set of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on a more rigorous proof of Baby Rudin's 4.31 Remark(a). This Remark has been discussed here before but mostly in an informal way, at least for (a).

(ps: the method below may be generalized for a cleaner proof, see my answer below)

[image]

I have a somewhat rigorous proof of (a) for arbitrary $\sum c_n$. Could anyone provide feedback/a better solution?

Say $a<x<y<b$. Define $\gamma(x) = \left\{ (n,c_n): x_n < x \right\}$ then if either $\gamma$ are finite we have $f(x) \le f(y)$ trivially. So we may assume both are countable. Note that $f(x) = \sum \gamma(x) := \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ where $(x_i)$ is any particular ordering of the countable bag $X(\gamma(x))= \left\{ c_n : (n,c_n) \in \gamma(x) \right\}$.

Let $\Delta(\gamma) := \gamma(y)-\gamma(x) = \{(n,c_n): x \le x_n < y\})$. If $\Delta(\gamma)$ is finite then we order $X(\gamma(y))$ by taking the first $|\Delta(\gamma)|=m$ elements to be $(d_1,\dots,d_m)$ where $\Delta(\gamma) = \{(m_i,d_i)\}$.  Having ordered the remaining elements of $X(\gamma(y))$ let $x_i = y_{i+m}$ be a ordering of $X(\gamma(x))$. If $s_n$ are the partials of $\sum y_i$ and $t_n$ of $\sum x_i$ we have
  \begin{equation*}
    s_{n+m} = t_n + \sum_{i\le m} d_i
  \end{equation*}
  taking $n \to \infty$
  \begin{equation*}
    f(y) = \sum \gamma(y) = \sum_{i\le m} d_i + \sum \gamma(x) \ge f(x)
  \end{equation*}
  Now say $\Delta(\gamma)$ is infinite then it must be countable and $X(\Delta(\gamma)) = \{d_1,d_2,\dots\}$ is a countable bag. Let $(x_i)$ be any ordering of $X(\gamma(x))$. Define a sequence $(y_i)$ with $y_{2n} = d_n$ and $y_{2n-1} = x_n$ then $(y_i)$ is an ordering of $X(\gamma(y))$ and we have
  \begin{equation*}
    T_{2n} := \sum_{i=1}^{2n} y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i
  \end{equation*}
  It follows that 
  \begin{equation}
    f(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} T_{2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} T_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \sum \Delta(\gamma) + f(x)
    \label{remark431a}
  \end{equation}
  and $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: I feel like $f(x) = \sum_{x_n < x} c_n \leq \sum_{x_n < x} c_n + \sum_{x \leq x_n< y} c_n = \sum_{x_n < y} c_n = f(y)$ should do it since all of the $c_n$ are positive and both sums are well-defined by definition.

Comment: That is the idea but the last equation seems a bit careless to me.

Comment: Well another way to think of this is to show that $f(y) - f(x) \geq 0$. We know beforehand that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are defined. So $f(y) - f(x) = \sum_{x\leq x_n < y}c_n$ is a number. This sum is either zero if there are no $x_n$ or positive there is at least one such $x_n$.

Comment: I suppose in my first comment, where I assume $\sum_{x\leq x_n < y} c_n$ is non-negative, I'm assuming the conclusion. Regardless, I feel that it is true almost by definition.

Comment: You're still manipulating the sums as if they were over a finite index set though. If at least one of the $\gamma$ above(that is, $\gamma(x)$) is finite then I agree that it is trivial. Don't get me wrong, I understand that since the sequence converges absolutely a lot of finite manipulations are still valid but Rudin has not used this fact at all.

Comment: Absolute convergence is key here - it allows you to re-arrange sums over any countable index set such as the ones we have here.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem, it is certainly non-negative. My only problem is with the equality. See the edited OP, the last expression is also useful for b) - which I found easier tbh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33827/discussion-between-b-freitas-and-danielson).

Comment: For both rigor and reader understandability, I suggest slightly rewriting danielson's (first comment) argument by making use of the notion of an *unordered sum*.

Comment: @Dave It seems that my disagreement with danielson's solution was caused by a different definition of rearrangement. He actually used a partitioning of the index set and not a reordering of the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following danielson's comment I realized we may generalize the method in the OP to any partition of the index set. (a) is then trivial indeed.

(Theorem) Let $\sum_{i \in I} x_i$ be a convergent at most countable sum of positive terms then if $A \cup B$ is a partition of $I$ we have
      \begin{equation*}
 \sum_{i \in I} x_i = \sum_{i \in A} x_i + \sum_{i \in B} x_i
      \end{equation*}

(Proof)
    If $I$ is finite then the result is trivial. Suppose $I$ is countable then the series of terms $x_n$ converges absolutely and the order in which we take the sum on the left is immaterial.
    If $A$ is finite let $A=(a_1,\dots,a_m)$. Extend $A$ to $C=(a_1,\dots,a_m,c_{m+1},\dots)$ then $(c_{m+1},c_{m+2},\dots)=(b_1,b_2,\dots)$ is an ordering of $B$ and we have
    \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{i=1}^{m+n} x_{c_i} = \sum_{i \in A} x_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{b_i}
 \end{equation*}
      Since $\sum x_{b_i}$ is a series of positive terms which is bound above by $\sum x_n$ it converges absolutely and order is irrelevant thus taking $n \to \infty$
      \begin{equation*}
 \sum_{i \in I} x_i = \sum_{i \in A} x_i + \sum_{i \in B} x_i
      \end{equation*}
    Now if both $A$ and $B$ are countable we take $A=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,\dots)$. Then $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots)=(c_1,c_2,\dots)$ is an ordering of $C$ and we have
    \begin{equation*}
      \sum_{i=1}^{2n} x_{c_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{a_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{b_i}
    \end{equation*}
    taking $n \to \infty$ and remembering that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same value the result follows.